# Why's my PDF Missing Color space, after I executed Preflight profile "Convert All Spots to CMYK"?

Tags: pdf

Please see the screenshot 2 beneath, after my failed attempt to fulfill [Step 3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005):

> 3. Search for **Convert All Spots to CMYK** and run **Fix**. Now all colors in your document are CMYK.

[image]

[As advised by the answerer, I had to create this fixup](https://superuser.com/a/1392166/269574), as my Adobe Acrobat DC Pro lacked it.

Comment: Can you once again provide the original PDF? It does not seem to be available anymore in your original inquiry here.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/9v8v6em2y2wst3f/Criminal+Law+%282018+8+ed%29+-+Herring+-+Deleted.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PDF doesn't have embedded color space (no ICC profile attached, no OutputIntent defined) so this error will come out for undefined colorspace objects. But for your particular case it doesn't matter, as you want to convert Pantone to default CMYK (probably US SWOP).

Comment: Thanks again! After screenshot 2, what do I do? I closed the Preflight window and then continued to [Step 4](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005), but I see no CMYK value on p. 22.

Comment: Please provide original PDF. I didn't saved it so it's hard to guess what exactly happening on page 22.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/9v8v6em2y2wst3f/Criminal+Law+%282018+8+ed%29+-+Herring+-+Deleted.pdf