# Why's there no CMYK value in 'Output Preview', after I executed the fixup to 'Convert All Spots to CMYK'?

Tags: pdf

Please see the combined screenshot beneath; I see no CMYK values? I'm trying to fulfill [step 4](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005):

> 4. Scroll to the page 22, as this is the first page with background fill you want to get rid of. Open again **Tools → Output Preview** and read CMYK value of the background. As I was converting *Pantone* with simulation to *U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2,* my CMYK values for background are 10:2:0:5. It's ok, if you will have different values. Just write them down as you will need to use them later.

[image]

Comment: For reviewers - this is linked to a previous question that had a bounty on it [https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/118636/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-that-backgrounds-only-some-text-in-a-pdf/118888#118888] and though as written here it seems both abstruse and context-less, it isn't really - just poorly written. Poster: please include enough context from that previous question that this reads as a stand-alone question which makes sense to those who've not seen the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Output Preview window open, roll your mouse over different parts of the PDF and it will display the CMYK percentages. Also, in the Output Preview window, where it says Preview: Separations, change that to Object Inspector. Then you can click on an element in your PDF, like a raster image or vector, and it will give you information about the image such as CMYK values and resolution.