# Why did I fail in my attempt to remove a blue background with Acrobat Pro DC's Preflight's Fixups?

Tags: pdf

What did I flub when following [these 6 steps](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005)? Please see the combined screenshot beneath.

[image]

Comment: In fifth step instead of destination "source color" try changing it to CMYK and set all values as 0.

Comment: @mrserge Done. Screenshot updated.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Thanks!!! It worked for this PDF. Let me try a few other PDFs in the next 24 hours and return to you.

Comment: @mrserge 1 - Of course. Screenshot updated. 2 - Please see my comment overhead ^^^. Please update https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005 if you'd like.

Comment: I don't see that something needs to be updated on my previous answer.

Comment: @mrserge Does https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119355/why-did-i-fail-in-my-attempt-to-remove-a-blue-background-with-acrobat-pro-dcs-p/119468#comment178005_119355 differ from your answer below?

Comment: No, solution is equal. You didn't complete setting up fixup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check background color in step 4 and write down CMYK value of the background.
2. Add this CMYK value to fixup as your target value.
3. Change in step 5 destination to CMYK and write in values 0:0:0:0.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that I didn't fulfill 3, but how didn't I fulfill 1 and 2 already? In screenshot 5, I input CMYK(10, 2, 0, 5). 2.

Comment: You did fulfill 1. and 2. I asked you to double check this only because other fault could be that background after conversation from Pantone have had different CMYK values.