# Where's 'Convert All Spots to CMYK' in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'm trying to complete Step 3 [beneath](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005),

> 2. Open **Tools → Print Production → Preflight** and switch to **Fixups**.
>      [image: Preflight -> Fixups]
> 3. Search for **Convert All Spots to CMYK** and run **Fix**. Now all colors in your document are CMYK.

but Acrobat's search engine isn't yielding 'Convert All Spots to CMYK'? See beneath.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own Fixup if you don't have it. Go to Create new Fixup and search for Map spot and process colors, create your own fixup based on that.

[image]