# Why did the fixup to 'Convert All Spots to CMYK' fail?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Why's [step 3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005) failing for [another PDF (click to download)](http://www.mediafire.com/file/x7803dheqjsaqch/EU_Law_%25282015_6_ed%2529_-_Paul_Craig%252C_Gr%25C3%25A1inne_de_B%25C3%25BArca_-_D%252C_Chapters_Deleted.pdf/file)? I didn't change anything about this fixup, since I last used it successfully in the aforementioned post (for the PDF for *Criminal Law*).  Anyway, screenshot 1 beneath proves that my fixup matches [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/119759/121005).

> 3. Search for **Convert All Spots to CMYK** and run **Fix**. Now all colors in your document are CMYK.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there some reason you have "Apply to" set to "None"?  The steps you refer to suggest it be set to "All vector and text objects". Also I think the Destination/Alternate Color model should be set to "CMYK".

Comment: @BillyKerr You're referring to Step 5. I was referring to https://superuser.com/a/1394111/269574.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal - I'm referring to step 5 in the link you referred to. You need to fix your question because it's not clear which steps you are trying to follow.

Comment: @BillyKerr I wrote in my post "But why's step 3 failing?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you must choose different fixup to do that, because that second spot color is something that giving an error. In this example I will show you how to convert spot color to specific destination CMYK.
You can modify your existing Spot color conversion fixup.

[image: setteings1]

1. Find «Convert colors» fixup in the list.
2. Set settings in Destination as it is shown below.
3. Remember that I choose for you U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2 profile. If you are in Europe, you would prefer to use PSO or ISO profiles, if you want to print in the end.

[image: settings 2]

4. Switch to Conversion settings and select to convert All Objects.
5. Then be sure to select that you want to convert Spot Colors. It would be better to use Absolute Colorimetric rendering intent.

Run the fixup and enjoy the results.

[image: results]

Comment: Hi again. Can you please explain 'In this case you must choose different fixup to do that, because that second spot color is something that giving an error.'? What's 'that second spot color' here'? Why's it 'giving an error'?

Comment: Can you please respond in (by editing) your answer? A chain of comments is more cumbersome to read.

Comment: There is nothing to correct. You have 2 spots in this example. That's all