# Why isn't 'Convert All Spots to CMYK' converting my PDF to CMYK, in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'm trying to fulfill [the steps beneath](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005), but I see no CMYK values in the screenshot beneath?

> 3. Search for **Convert All Spots to CMYK** and run **Fix**. Now all colors in your document are CMYK.
> 4. Scroll to the page 22, as this is the first page with background fill you want to get rid of. Open again **Tools → Output Preview** and read CMYK value of the background. As I was converting *Pantone* with simulation to *U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2,* my CMYK values for background are 10:2:0:5. It's ok, if you will have different values. Just write them down as you will need to use them later.

[image]

What have I done wrongly? I screenshot the steps beneath.

[image]

Comment: You didn't convert object to CMYK, you see Pantone values as object is in spot color.

Comment: @mrserge Thanks again. (1) Can you please see the combined screenshots that I added just now? Whatt's wrong? (2) Please feel free to copy and paste your answer from Graphic Design to https://superuser.com/q/1388370/269574.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In color selection you left RegEx expression empty so the Fix didn't select anything. You must write in RegEx expression **.*** (dot and asterisk).

[image: RegEx is empty]