# Why isn't the 'Map colors' fixup removing a gray background?

Tags: pdf

Why's [step 5](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005) failing for [this PDF (click here to download the original)](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ3U6d7Z2HcVD2M2EhFvim4a2C7JFS89QdBy)?   As you can see beneath, the gray background remains. Steps 3 and 4 succeeded though: [here's](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ05ld7ZOXvq01EhodzIcuNmQi5YMRN96Xi7) the resulting PDF.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has to do with the color space. The box in question uses ICCbased RGB - but you are right: just decalibrating it does not suffice.

What you should do is first analyze the box in Preflight. You can do so using the "List page objects grouped by type of object" profile and you can limit that to one page.

The screenshot shows that the color of the box is 0.82/0.81/0.88 in RGB. You can now put that value into the Map colors fixup which needs to be set up for the accurate color space of the object.

[image]

[This download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6d0bmjyr1h8q75/MapDarkGray2White.zip?dl=0) has the screenshot, that fixup, and the result.

Comment: Proper protocols are to edit your previous answer and not just make a new answer.

Comment: Thanks. (1) So why did Step 5 (in that other post) fail here? (2)  Why did you write 'you can limit that to one page'? I was trying to remove all grey backgrounds.

Comment: (1) I am not sure, what "other post" you mean.

Comment: (2) I was suggesting to limit the //analysis// to one page. If you apply that to the whole PDF you will see details for many objects and it is more difficult to identify the one that you are interested in.

Comment: @DietrichvonSeggern (1) I was referring to step 5 in https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005.

Comment: Can you please respond in, by editing, your answer? Comment chains are
cumbersome to read.

Comment: Sorry: can you please re-upload your download link? It has vanished.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to say without seeing the file. Could be that the boxes are using ICCbased RGB. In that case, you should first decalibrate. Here is a Preflight profile that should accomplish that: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwim64nnom7itoq/Decalibrate%20ICCbased%20RGB.kfp?dl=0

Comment: The file in linked in the question. Additionally, your answer doesn't solve the problem. Simply converting the colors does nothing to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you please combine this answer with other, and delete this?