# Which one of 'Convert colors' and 'Map colors' Fixups are unnecessary?

Tags: pdf, color-conversion, adobe-acrobat

I'm using Adobe Acrobat to change colors in a PDF.

1. Using merely 1 Fixup is obviously easier than 2. So is one Fixup a subset of the other? To wit, which is more all-encompassing?
2. Which Fixup can I delete from my list, without losing any capability?
3. As [mrserge](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005)  used the 'Map colors' fixup on Jan 8 2019, but needed  'Convert colors' fixup on Feb 1 2019, I'm guessing 'Map colors' ⊂ 'Convert colors' ?

Answer (score 2):

These are two completely different functions. They are not redundant to each other. Convert Colors is used to manipulate things like document color space, applying color profiles, and altering the color of objects within the document. Mapping deals with reassigning spot colors to other specific colors in a non-destructive way. Spot swatches can be flagged so that they print as other spot colors, or as process (CMYK). These are both quite useful, and entirely separate functions.