# Does mrserge's answer still work if I convert all spots to RGB, rather than CMYK?

Tags: pdf

Please read [mrserge's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118888/121005) and the question there before reading this question. mrserge answered

> What we will do: convert everything to CMYK, then replace specific CMYK value with other and we will do that by using standard Acrobat Pro Fixups.
>
> [...]
>
> 3. Search for **Convert All Spots to CMYK** and run **Fix**. Now all colors in your document are CMYK.

Question 1. I'm assuming that RGB is easier to work with than CMYK, as RGB has just 3 integers but CMYK 4.

2. How can mrserge's answer be adapted to work with RGB?

Comment: Wht are you assuming that working in RGB is easier? Under what condition? Anyway they are not harder or easier to work with, they are more appropriate to different media

Comment: @joojaa Because 'RGB has just 3 integers but CMYK 4'? Also because every color can be represented in RGB or CMYK?

Comment: Have you tried to simply follow the steps of mrserge's answer but choosing RGB every time he chooses CMYK? What exactly gives you problems? (Sometimes it's not recommended to work in RGB - for example ordinary black text should be defined as CMYK(0, 0, 0, 100) and *not* rgb(0, 0, 0) because the text looks more crisp when it's only printed with one ink. No RGB color can ensure that.)

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal i fail to see how that makes it easier to do printing? Its not inherenlty easier to define color as 3 integers than 4 percentages. Neither is harder nor easier, just different. Theres no basis for the assumption. Anyway not every color can be represented in CMYK and RGB.